# Strange defragmentation tool : free space reduced after defragmentation

Tags: windows-vista, defragment

I used **diskeeper** for defragmenting my C drive on vista. Initially I had 2.6 GB free space, after defragmentation, it is just 480 MB. What happened? Please help to recover the space. Defragmentation is not supposed to decrease the storage space!!!

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Obtained by Scanner tool as suggested by ~harrymc in his answer

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I do not have much idea of above diagram. But I can infer one thing. From the above diagram, it looks like there is a problem. For e.g., in the green portion(representing folder) on the right at first level, there is a small portion on top right hand side which does not lead to any actual file. So the portion below it must not have been green. It should be free. **Am I correct in my interpretation ?**

**Edit 3:**

I ran `chkdsk /f`. It ran at restart. It removed some index entries. It gave message like this:

```
removed $0 of file 25
```

repeated many times. But the problem is still there. Please help.

**Edit 4:**

**Mysteriuosly, just 2 minutes ago it has started showing me free space as 2.3 GB. I swear, I did not delete any thing Just 4 minutes ago, it was showing me 290 MB. I dont understand, how suddenly that space got freed. What is happening? Could anyone explain? I got this after running scanner now.**

[image]

Comment: it didn't "increase the storage space", now did it? :)

Comment: Whatever, I have lost so much free space. Pls help.

Comment: What metrics are you using to count the free space on your machine?

Comment: The space shown by windows explorer under the icons of c drive.

Comment: About Edit 4: am I reading this right, you got your free space back? In that case I'd guess chkdsk did the trick.
Remember, the free space display is not always immediately updated. You might have looked at old results after chkdsk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note: It's always advisable to do chkdsk before defragmenting.

You'll need to find out where the space has gone.
Things to try:

1. Right-click the C drive in Explorer and choose Properties. Verify that the total used+unused space still corresponds to the disk size.
2. If the total disk space is correct, but the used part is enormous, find out where the space has gone to. Using a visual tool such as [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/), you can find that out easily.
3. **EDIT:** Run [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) to remove unused files from your system.

Comment: Ok i m doing that. But it will take some time.

Comment: The point is, it *wasn't* Diskeeper.

Comment: Then what else? This thing happened only after running diskeeper

Comment: What shouuld I post? It shows me the diagram. hovering over shows info about differenet files. Should I post just the diagram?

Comment: I have posted the results. How should I understand from this diagram? I did not understand. How should I check?

Comment: right, Randolp Potter, it wasn't Diskeeper, why would the Scientology Church do such a nasty thing and deprive you of precious disk space? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskeeper_Corporation#Scientology_and_Diskeeper

Comment: Please solve my problem.

Comment: To see where the disk space is used simply move the cursor over the pie slices. The larger the pie, the more space it takes. You can see on the top left the name and disk-size of the pie slice. Since you're looking for something like 3GB out of 90GB, the pie slice will not be large. Just try to find something that looks unnecessary (but verify it with us). One directory that you can always empty is C:\Windows\Temp (but be careful not to delete the directory itself or anything else in C:\Windows).

Comment: Is there any easier way? Looking for each file is very cumbersome?

Comment: See 3rd point in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have had [sparse files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365564(VS.85).aspx) on the volume, and DiskKeeper made the sparse sektors allocate real space? Not sure if DiskKeeper does this, but it would explain the loss in free space.

Anyway, run a chkdsk /f, use a tool like [sequioa view](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/) to find large files on your harddisk.

Comment: How can I undo it? I have posted the diagram for large files in my question  as suggested by ~harrymc in his answer using Scanner tool

Comment: Ya I ran chkdsk/f. It removed some index entries. But the space is still not recovered. After finding large files what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know scanner and got no idea how to use its output. You should use Scanner/Sequioa to identify large files on your system, then check if there are obsolete files which can be deleted.

And I don't know of any way to undo sparse file allocation. Always try not to allocate them in the first place (so, if really diskkeeper did allocate them, never again use it).

Answer (score 1):

2.6 GB free space after installation is not a value Windows will be happy with for long. If you can, you should reinstall on a bigger partition. The unavoidable patches will fill that space up in no time, and Windows will be in trouble.

Perhaps the Swap file is set to "automatic", and during the defragmentation Windows had to allocate some virtual memory.

Check your event logs for disk errors.

Answer (score 0):

Diskeeper will not use up 2.2GB of space by performing a defragmentation (or ever).

I would suggest that your Windows System Restore added a restore point during Diskeeper's installation.

**EDIT**: It appears you had allocation errors, based on your *chkdisk* results. Run it again until the errors go away.

Do a regular chkdsk. File systems need to be maintained, and if you get any bad sectors, you'll need to find a new drive.

Comment: No the free space 2.6 GB space was after installation

Comment: Do what harrymc suggested then, and check for large files on your machine.

Comment: I did not understand. How should I check?

Comment: Use Windows search...

Comment: Please tell me what exactly should I do? with Search?

Comment: What is the meaning of bad sectors? Means u wrote that bad sectors means a new hard hard. Why?

Comment: Bad sectors are usually a sign of physical damage to the drive, and they have a tendency to get worse (i.e. "spread") over time. So if you do pick up bad sectors in a chkdisk, it is recommended that you back up your data and replace the drive.

Answer (score 0):

One way to free up some space, not related to this is change your Recycle Bin size. Right click and go to properties and adjust the slider bars there. Who needs s 4gb recycle bin?! =]

Comment: My recycle bin currently takes up less than 1 MB. The problem is not this. The problem is space actually being utilised.